# Why does App Insights NUGET add 2 AdapativeSamplingTelemetryProcessor nodes?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, telemetry, azure-application-insights-profiler

In the ApplicationInsights.config this node (see below) is being added twice, although they are not identical.

> Why is it being added twice like this? It appears the 2nd node is just
>   negating the 1st node (its just including what the 1st node is
>   excluding). Is this a bug?

```
<TelemetryProcessors>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.AutocollectedMetricsExtractor, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights"/>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel">
      <MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>5</MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>
      <ExcludedTypes>Event</ExcludedTypes>
    </Add>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel">
      <MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>5</MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>
      <IncludedTypes>Event</IncludedTypes>
    </Add>
  </TelemetryProcessors>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's by default.

Please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling#frequently-asked-questions) for more details. Provide a screenshot of that article:

[image]

Comment: So what would i need to do to exclude another telemetry type from being sampled? My guess would be to simply add it to the IncludedTypes element?